# Increase font size on target board using Qt for Embedded Linux

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

I'm developing with Qt for Embedded Linux and Qt 4.7.1 on Linux and I'm cross compiling for an ARM board with Digi som. On the Qt application that runs on the ARM board using Digi ESP for embedded Linux, I need some QLabels with large fonts (I set to 48pt on the QtDesigner).

However when I load the executable on the ARM board those fonts are not as large as I see them on the QtDesigner interface (and on my Linux PC), and even if I set a bigger font size, when I run the application on the board, the fonts have always the same size (as if it were reached a maximum font size or as if the font does not support that size).

I have tried everything from makeqpf (which does not compile) to build qt with freetype but nothing seems to work.

Comment: When you said `you load the executable on the ARM board` what is the display screen you are using to see your application. There are certain environment variables that you need to set before as per the screen dimension/properties.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I tried setting the QT_QWS_FONTDIR environment variable to the target's font directory.  My code currently states the fontsize is set to 48. (font.setPointSize(48)). But the target is not able to display a 48 font size. The maximum it displays is 24. Has it got to do with the fact that my target's qt/lib/fonts folder has Helvetica_240_80.qpf as the largest font, which is why the font size does not go beyond 24? If so, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set an environment variable called QWS_DISPLAY with it's dimensions on the target and that solved the problem. Thank you for the hint user12345